# A fast question about GVT-g Intel?

Tags: hardware, video

I read this [howto](https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide) and have the following questions:

Is this like the GPU passthrough VFIO (you need two monitors and two different graphic cards, and a motherboard which supports IOMMU feature)?

Or is possible to assign a virtual GPU to guest which can run graphic apps (games or apps needing direct card access) using only one card (of course if GVT-g is supported)?

Comment: Sounds like this is very much a work in progress - https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2018-April/msg00019.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Is this like the GPU passthrough VFIO (you need two monitors and two different graphic cards, and a motherboard which supports IOMMU feature)?

Looking at this slide from this video on Youtube titled: [Intel GVT-g: From Production to Upstream - Zhi Wang, Intel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UODxW1opfn0), it looks like you have to have a motherboard that supports IOMMU.

[image: ss1]

Also looking at this slide, it looks like you just have to have a single GPU. Regarding your last question.

> Q2: Or is possible to assign a virtual GPU to guest which can run graphic apps (games or apps needing direct card access) using only one card (of course if GVT-g is supported)?

It looks like the guest OSes through QENU will use VFIO MDEV via their GFX drivers internal to them.

[image: ss2]